# Binding array of object to Kendo grid popup multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to bind an array of id-value pairs to a kendo grid popup editor.

Got everything to work for creating a new record. Popup editor loads the custom editor and successfully submits the data to the controller.

The problem is when I try to edit records. The records displays properly in the row, but when I try to edit it, the multiselect does not hold the values.

Grid Markup

```
    $("#ProjectSites-SubContract-grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",                
            schema: {
                data: "Data",
                total: "Total",
                errors: "Errors",
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        DateOfContract: { type: 'date', editable: true },
                        DateOfCompletion: { type: 'date', editable: true },
                        AmountOfContract: { type: 'number', editable: true },
                        Contractor: { defaultValue: { id: "", name: "" } }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        columns: [            
        {
            field: "ScopeOfWork",
            title: "Scope of Work",
            template: "#=parseScopeOfWork(ScopeOfWork)#",
            editor: scopeOfWorkEditor
        },            
        ]
    });
});
```

Scope of Work editor

```
function scopeOfWorkEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input  data-text-field="name" data-value-field="id" data-bind="value:ScopeOfWork"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoMultiSelect({
            dataSource: {
                data: [
                    @foreach (var scopeOfWork in Model.AvailableScopeOfWork)
                    {
                        <text>{ id : "@scopeOfWork.Value", name : "@scopeOfWork.Text" },</text>
                    },
                ]
            }
        });
```

parseScopeOfWork -
this method guys iterates through the object list and concats the name.

```
function parseScopeOfWork(scopeOfWork) {
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < scopeOfWork.length; i++) {
        result += scopeOfWork[i].Name;
        if (i < scopeOfWork.length - 1)
        {
            result += ", <br/>";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding the `SpaceOfWork` to the new widget, but how that widget knows your Model ? I mean, just using `data-bind` doens't binds the model to the widget, it can't figure that by itself. I have two suggestions:

1. Set the value in the widget's initialization:

   ```
   .kendoMultiSelect({
       value: options.model.ScopeOfWork
   ```

   [Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/esIbEnUz)
2. Bind the model to the widget for good:

   ```
   let $multiSelect = $('<input data-text-field="name" data-value-field="id" data-bind="value:ScopeOfWork"/>');

   kendo.bind($multiSelect, options.model);

   $multiSelect
       .appendTo(container)
       .kendoMultiSelect({ ...
   ```

   [Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/esIbEnUz/2)

<sup>Note: Edit the category cell in both demos to see the changes.</sup>