# Kendo UI MVC Grid Popup editor display date field formatted

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc grid with a custom popup editor that I want to display a date time in. How do you format the date when using this type of binding?

```
<span type="date" data-format="MM/dd/yyyy" data-bind="text: CreatedOn"></span>
```

But is still shows up as: `Thu Jun 18 2020 12:43:48 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use kendo template notation here

```
<div class="k-edit-label">
    <label for="CreatedOn">#= kendo.toString((CreatedOn), "d") #</label>
</div>
```

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/globalization/intl/dateformatting

Comment: also found an example using mvc http://dojo.telerik.com/@PMcDonou/eNovu

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the format you can use for the MVC version. You need to use a different method of data binding. This gives some clues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470875/kendoui-grid-popup-edit-template-validation-not-picking-up-model-validation-rule. or the 3rd comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703500/kendo-mvc-grid-customized-popup-edit-template-validation-not-working

Comment: And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556577/binding-array-of-object-to-kendo-grid-popup-multiselect. And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54823314/kendo-ui-bind-drop-down-value-from-popupeditor

Comment: @ChadRichardson Actually the popup in my project also looks like that style, with model binding. What I did if you are going with this approach is to put the date in a datepickerfor and then make it readonly.

Comment: @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.FirstDate).HtmlAttributes(new { @readonly = "readonly" })

Comment: Thank you. I don't mean to sound picky, but I don't want the weightiness of the date picker, I just want the date. This is shown in a small font at the bottom that shows when a record was modified. The client also wants it to look like the Last Modified Date on all the regular pages. There's got to be a way to get the raw model data so you can format it.